# Is "In such a case" wrong?

Tags: indefinite-articles

"In such a case" doesn't sound right. Is it necessary to use "a" ? Is it wrong if one omits it?

Comment: If you are talking about a single case then you must use *a*  if you are talking about multiple cases then you use the plural: *in such cases*.  But it will be one of those two.

Comment: "In _that_ case" could be appropriate, but we have no context.

Answer (score 3):

Jim's comment is correct:

> If you are talking about a single case then you must use *a*. If you are talking about multiple cases then you use the plural: *in such cases*. But it will be one of those two.